# C++ #define value not defined in source file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I'm defining a value in my Main-file and then including a header file. The defined value isn't defined in the source file.

Main.cpp:

```
#define TN_VALUE double
#include "SomeFile.hpp"

int main()
{
  TN_VALUE x = 3;
  func(x);
  return 0;
}
```

SomeFile.hpp:

```
#ifndef _SOME_FILE
#define _SOME_FILE
#ifndef TN_VALUE
#define TN_VALUE float
#endif
void func(TN_VALUE); // TN_VALUE = double
#endif
```

SomeFile.cpp:

```
#include "SomeFile.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void func(TN_VALUE _value) // TN_VALUE = float
{
  std::cout << _value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It's defined in both cases. I'm not sure what exactly you are asking. Are you asking why it's `double` in one file and `float` in the other?

Comment: What makes you think it's not defined? And you have two #define statements for `TN_VALUE`, one as double and one as float. Why in the world would you do that?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_SOME_FILE`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your question is, 
Why does `TN_VALUE` is `double` in `Main.cpp` and `float` in `SomeFile.cpp`.

For that question, this is the explanation, 
In C++, when you include a header file, it's content gets copied to the source file. Which means that there will be one copy of the `SomeFile.hpp` file in `Main.cpp` file and another copy in the `SomeFile.cpp` file. So now when the compiler runs through the source file, in one file the definition of `TN_VALUE` is `float` (in `SomeFile.cpp`) and its value is `double` (because you have defined it explicitly) in the other file (`Main.cpp`). 
This means that there will be two different (overloaded) functions. One is `void func(float)` and the other is `void func(double)`.

Since the function definition is present in the `SomeFile.cpp` file, it'll compile without an issue, but the `Main.cpp` file will have an issue because the compiler says that there's a function with the signature of `void func(double)` which the linker cannot find (because a function like that is not compiled). This will trigger a link error.

To resolve this issue, you can define the function in the header file itself and ditch the `SomeFile.cpp` file altogether. This way the function definition will be placed in the `Main.cpp` file and the definition of the `TN_VALUE` will resolve to `double`. No linking errors will arise from this function after that.

Answer (score 0):

We can investigate what the preprocessed code looks like with `g++`'s `-E` flag:

> Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper. The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent to the standard output.

<sup>([source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++))</sup>

Here is the preprocessed code for `Main.cpp`:

```
$ g++ -E Main.cpp 
# 1 "Main.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "Main.cpp"

# 1 "SomeFile.hpp" 1





void func(double);
# 3 "Main.cpp" 2

int main()
{
  double x = 3;
  func(x);
  return 0;
}
```

And here is the preprocessed code for `SomeFile.cpp`, if we remove the `#include <iostream>`:

```
$ g++ -E SomeFile.cpp
# 1 "SomeFile.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "SomeFile.cpp"
# 1 "SomeFile.hpp" 1





void func(float);
# 2 "SomeFile.cpp" 2


void func(float _value)
{
  std::cout << _value << std::endl;
}
```

What we can see, is that in `Main.cpp`, `TN_VALUE` is `double`, and therefore we get `void func(double);` and `double x = 3;`. In `SomeFile.cpp`, `TN_VALUE` is `float`. Why is this?

This all has to do with the

```
#ifndef TN_VALUE
#define TN_VALUE float
#endif
```

in `SomeFile.hpp`. This tells the preprocessor that, if `TN_VALUE` is not defined, set `TN_VALUE` to `float`. If `TN_VALUE` is defined, do nothing (leave `TN_VALUE` with the value it has.

In `Main.cpp`, you have

```
#define TN_VALUE double
#include "SomeFile.hpp"
```

The order here means that `TN_VALUE` will be defined before the preprocessor reaches the `ifndef` in `SomeFile.hpp`, and so `TN_VALUE` will keep the `double` value.

Then in `SomeFile.cpp`, you immediately have `#include "SomeFile.hpp"`. Since `SomeFile.cpp` is a separate translation unit from `Main.cpp`, `TN_VALUE` is not defined. That means, since `TN_VALUE` is not set when the preprocessor gets to the `ifndef` in `SomeFile.hpp`, the preprocessor will reach the `#define TN_VALUE float` line, which will cause it to set `TN_VALUE` to `float`.

#### More `g++ -E` analysis

If this was a larger and more complicated code base, we might have wanted to isolate the problem more carefully by looking just at `SomeFile.hpp` and the preprocessed output generated with different defines.

We can look at the preprocessed output of `SomeFile.hpp` with no defines:

```
$ g++ -E SomeFile.hpp
# 1 "SomeFile.hpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "SomeFile.hpp"





void func(float);
```

We can also use `g++`'s `-D` flag to make a define. If we use `-D TN_VALUE=double`, we should see something matching the `Main.cpp` case:

```
$ g++ -D TN_VALUE=double -E SomeFile.hpp
# 1 "SomeFile.hpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "SomeFile.hpp"





void func(double);
```

We already expected these results from our analysis above. However, this demonstrates that we can test what preprocessed code is generated by any C or C++ header file based on the various values of different defines.